# Threaded class variable not being set correctly

Tags: java, android, multithreading, volatile

I have a threaded class shown below, which should terminate upon `m_bExit` being set to false. The boolean `m_bMessageReceived` is set externally.

```
public class CommsTimeout extends Thread {

    public static boolean m_bMessageReceived = false;
    public volatile boolean m_bExit = false;
    private static long m_nStartTime;

    public void run() {

        while (!m_bExit) {
            while ((System.currentTimeMillis() < (m_nStartTime + Constants.PERIOD))) {
                // Wait...
            }
            if (!m_bMessageReceived) {
                // Do stuff.
            }

            m_bMessageReceived = false;
        }
    }

    public CommsTimeout() {

        // Reset flags.
        m_bMessageReceived = false;
        m_bExit = false;
        m_nStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.start();
    }
}
```

The `CommsTimeout` class is being initialised in another class...

```
m_threadCommsTimeout = new CommsTimeout();
```

... and `m_bMessageReceived` is being set as so in another class every few miliseconds:

```
CommsTimeout.m_bMessageReceived = true;
```

My problem is that even though `m_bMessageReceived` is being set to `true` within the timeout period, the `// Do stuff` line is still being reached. What have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: What is `Constants.PERIOD`??

Comment: That is equal to 5000 so the while loop iterates for 5 seconds.

Comment: You're setting m_bMessageReceived to false right after checking it, so on the next iteration of the while it will be false and "Do stuff" if this iteration of the loop doesn't exceed your Constants.PERIOD.

Comment: @VeselinTodorov Thanks you're right, I should be resetting the `m_nStartTime` variable when I set `m_bMessageReceived` to false...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a visibility issue. There is no guarantee that your thread will see the change to `m_bMessageReceived` when the variable is set in a different thread. Try making `m_bMessageReceived` `volatile`. This will ensure that your thread will see the most recent value of the variable.